# C++ class member function assignment

Tags: c++11

This is a c++ assignment that I am working on:

```
//Numbers Class
#ifndef NUMBERS_H
#define NUMBERS_H
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

class Numbers
{
private:
    static int number;

public:
    void setNumber(int x)
    {
        number = x;
    }
    int getNumber() const
    {
        return number;
    }
    void print();
};

void Numbers::print()
{
static string lessThan20[21] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three",
                        "four", "five", "six", "seven",
                        "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven",
                        "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
                        "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen",
                        "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty"};
static string tens[10] = {"zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty",
                    "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy",
                    "eighty", "ninety"};
static string hundred = "hundred";
static string thousand = "thousand";

int processedNumber;
int thousandsRemainder;
int hundredsRemainder;
int tensRemainder;
int singlesRemainder;
processedNumber = Numbers.getNumber();   \\ This line
processedNumber = abs(processedNumber);
thousandsRemainder= processedNumber / 1000;
if (thousandsRemainder > 1)
{
    cout << lessThan20[thousandsRemainder] << " " << thousand << " ";
    processedNumber -= thousandsRemainder * 1000;
}
hundredsRemainder = processedNumber / 100;
if (hundredsRemainder > 1)
{
    cout << lessThan20[hundredsRemainder] << " " << hundred << " ";
    processedNumber -= hundredsRemainder * 100;
}
if(processedNumber < 21)
{
    cout << lessThan20[processedNumber];
}
else
{
    tensRemainder = processedNumber/10;
    cout << tens[tensRemainder] << " ";
    processedNumber -= tensRemainder * 10;
    if(processedNumber > 1)
        cout << lessThan20[processedNumber];
}

} // End of class
#endif
```

I am new to working with classes, and have read through many tutorials, but I can not find any similar code to learn from that will help me with the problem I am having.

My problem lies on the line:

```
processedNumber = Numbers.getNumber();
```

I am not sure how to assign the value of number to processedNumber. What is the correct way to assign the value of number to processedNumber?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Just plain `processedNumber = getNumber();`

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried that one many times.